# Jenkins: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean, but execution happens from command prompt

Tags: linux, maven, jenkins

I am trying to run a maven project from Jenkins in my local machine.
I am new to Maven and Jenkins and trying to get hands on by trying to run a project from jenkins locally.
I have created a simple jenkins job with below details:

> POM xml path
>
> goals: clean test

Please note that the execution runs perfectly when I execute it via terminal
Also I am working on a linux operating system.

However when I build the project I get below issue:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) on project geekyant: Failed to clean project: Failed to delete /home/shsing/Desktop/mobile-automation/MedlifeCustomerapp/target/test-classes/Pages/linksPage.class -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) on project geekyant: Failed to clean project: Failed to delete /home/shsing/Desktop/mobile-automation/MedlifeCustomerapp/target/test-classes/Pages/linksPage.class
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.maven3.launcher.Maven35Launcher.main (Maven35Launcher.java:130)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at jenkins.maven3.agent.Maven35Main.launch (Maven35Main.java:178)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call (Maven3Builder.java:139)
    at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call (Maven3Builder.java:70)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform (UserRequest.java:212)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform (UserRequest.java:54)
    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run (Request.java:369)
    at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call (InterceptingExecutorService.java:72)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run (FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Failed to clean project: Failed to delete /home/shsing/Desktop/mobile-automation/MedlifeCustomerapp/target/test-classes/Pages/linksPage.class
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.clean.CleanMojo.execute (CleanMojo.java:215)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.maven3.launcher.Maven35Launcher.main (Maven35Launcher.java:130)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at jenkins.maven3.agent.Maven35Main.launch (Maven35Main.java:178)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call (Maven3Builder.java:139)
    at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call (Maven3Builder.java:70)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform (UserRequest.java:212)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform (UserRequest.java:54)
    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run (Request.java:369)
    at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call (InterceptingExecutorService.java:72)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run (FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to delete /home/shsing/Desktop/mobile-automation/MedlifeCustomerapp/target/test-classes/Pages/linksPage.class
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.clean.Cleaner.delete (Cleaner.java:249)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.clean.Cleaner.delete (Cleaner.java:191)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.clean.Cleaner.delete (Cleaner.java:158)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.clean.Cleaner.delete (Cleaner.java:158)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.clean.Cleaner.delete (Cleaner.java:158)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.clean.Cleaner.delete (Cleaner.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.clean.CleanMojo.execute (CleanMojo.java:208)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.maven3.launcher.Maven35Launcher.main (Maven35Launcher.java:130)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at jenkins.maven3.agent.Maven35Main.launch (Maven35Main.java:178)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call (Maven3Builder.java:139)
    at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call (Maven3Builder.java:70)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform (UserRequest.java:212)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform (UserRequest.java:54)
    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run (Request.java:369)
    at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call (InterceptingExecutorService.java:72)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run (FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:748)
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
[JENKINS] Archiving /home/shsing/Desktop/mobile-automation/MedlifeCustomerapp/pom.xml to com.medlife/geekyant/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/geekyant-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
/home/shsing/Desktop/mobile-automation/MedlifeCustomerapp/pom.xml is not inside /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/newJob2/home/shsing/Desktop/mobile-automation/MedlifeCustomerapp/; will archive in a separate pass
channel stopped
Finished: FAILURE
```

Expected: The execution should happen even via jenkins as i am successfully able to execute via terminal

Comment: Looks like your jenkins instance has insuffient permissions to delete the files in the project. As which user are you running jenkins?

Comment: Hi. How can i check this? I am new to jenkins so do not know where to get this info,.

Comment: Please run the maven with -X switch to see full error logs. And then share it here so that we can see the root cause. Most probably its permission problem as jenkins runs the job as jenkins user and not the actual user which you are using the machine as.

Comment: Hi @VighneshPai, Have attached the full logs. Kindly have a look

Comment: @ShivPratapSingh How did you start jenkins? You can also try to find out with 'ps ax'.

Comment: Looks like a permission issue. Can u try running a shell script before the maven clean test? sudo chmod +x /home/shsing/Desktop/mobile-automation/

Comment: I'm sure you will come across that u cannot run the command as sudo from jenkins. For that, on the linux machine run sudo visudo and at the very end of that file add jenkins    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

Comment: btw this is a workaround for now. It's not recommended to mess with permissions :)

Comment: Hi @VighneshPai, Tried the same way as suggested by you. But still facing the same issue.

Comment: Hi @DrHopfen, I have tried by changing the jenkins user in  etc/default/jenkins file. But once i change i am not able to open jenkins

Comment: Thanks for your help guys. It was a permission issue after all.Was able to fix the issue by following below steps:<br/ > 
1.  open etc/default/jenkins and update the value of variable JENKINS_USER to your user  
            then change the ownership for below files  
             chown -R userName /var/lib/jenkins  
             chown -R userName /var/log/jenkins  
             chown -R userName /var/cache/jenkins   
             chown -R userName /var/run/jenkins/  restart jenkins at last

Answer (score 3):

Resolve your permission issue for your jenkins setting by following below steps:

1.Access terminal as root user

```
sudo -i
```

2. Open /etc/default/jenkins in any editor such as nano or vi and change the following details:

```
nano /etc/default/jenkins
```

3. Inside file, update the value of variable JENKINS_USER to your user for example(instead of JENKINS_USER=$NAME use this JENKINS_USER=your_user_name)

4.Change the ownership of following file by running following command:

```
chown -R your_user_name /var/lib/jenkins
chown -R your_user_name /var/log/jenkins
chown -R your_user_name /var/cache/jenkins
chown -R your_user_name /var/run/jenkins
```

5. Restart your jenkins by running following command:

```
systemctl restart jenkins
```

All Done.